# Insert GET value and a line break on PHP file

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
$file = 'gclids.php';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $_GET['gclid'];
$current .= "\r\n"
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

It basically loads the content of a list (gclids.php) in $current and append a parameter from google adwords ($_GET['gclid']) to $current. Then, it SHOULD append a line break to $current so we should have something like this:

```
xyz
zyx
xyz
zyx
```

But it fails to append the line break, so we have something like this:

```
xyzzyxxyzzyx
```

So, in general:

> Script receive value -> Save it to a list

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a remote execution vulnerability waiting to happen. Use a format like JSON or INI for your text file. Or heck, even plain text. Just don't give it a `.php` extension.

Comment: browsers expect html `<br>` not `\r\n`

Comment: Not only `.php`! Simply `.html` can be evil too. It can contain JS script who running some XHR requests with all cookies to access private user's data (if user will receive its link and open it in his browser). You should at least use `htmlspecialchars` to emasculate all "<" and ">" inside input string. Problematic approach...

Comment: Also you could do it with just `file_put_contents($file, $_GET['gclid'].PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: `$current .= "\r\n"` < is that not missing closure here? It is.